# POST request works on cURL but not when using wp_remote_post

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, curl

I'm executing successfully the follow request:

```
curl -X POST \
  http://apitoconnect.com/v1/tracking \
  -H 'authorization: Basic dm...........PQ==' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
"CarrierName": "xxxxxx",
"OrderNumber": "111111",
"ReceiptNumber": "0000000",
"ReceiptSerie": "0",
"Code": "0000000000",
"DateToDelivery": "2017-10-03",
"CompanyDocumentNumber": "00000000",
"CustomerEmail": "xxxx@yyyy.com",
"CustomerDocumentNumber": "000000000",
"CustomerPostalCode": "0000000000",
"SendSms": "true",
"SendEmail": "true",
"CustomerPhone": "00000000000",
"CustomerName": "Bill Gates",
"SalesChannel": "00000000"
}'
```

It works just fine! But when I try to make this using WordPress, I always get error 500.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $token,
        'Content-Type'  => 'application/json'
    ),
    'body' => array(
        'OrderNumber'            => '111111',
        'ReceiptNumber'          => '0000000',
        'ReceiptSerie'           => '0',
        'Code'                   => '0000000000',
        'DateToDelivery'         => '2017-10-03',
        'CarrierName'            => 'xxxxxx',
        'CompanyDocumentNumber'  => '00000000',
        'CustomerEmail'          => 'xxxx@yyyy.com',
        'CustomerPhone'          => '00000000000',
        'CustomerName'           => 'Bill Gates',
        'CustomerDocumentNumber' => '000000000',
        'CustomerPostalCode'     => '0000000000',
        'SendSms'                => true,
        'SendEmail'              => true,
        'SalesChannel'           => '00000000',
    )
);

$response = wp_remote_post( esc_url_raw( $url ), $args );
```

I tried to `json_encode( )` the array of parameters, but it didn't work too...

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Check php error log on the side of your api. It should give you a good starting hint.

Comment: Did you json_encode the body or the entire $args? Seems like 'body' should just be a JSON-encoded array, so maybe:

    $args["body"] = json_encode($args["body"]);

Comment: What I tried was just the body - `'body' => json_encode( array( ... ) )`. The way I wrote was confusing, sorry

Comment: @rndus2r: The API is third-party. I have no access to any log there...

Comment: What version of WordPress are you running?

Comment: Latest version: 4.8.2

Answer (score 1):

Within and outside of the WP rest API, at least on my server configuration, you need to manually set the user agent.

```
$headers = array('Content-type' => 'application/json', 'user-agent'=>$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

Comment: The user agent worked for me, why would one set a restriction on a payment gateway (in my case)